# trying to Insert an image into a filemaker container using C#

Tags: c#, sql, image, odbc, filemaker

I'm need to insert an image into a filemaker container with an insert statement, and while the odbc documentation seems vague without clear examples, I'm trying to get it to work on a simple level as follows:

command line as appears in text visualizer for sqlstr:

```
INSERT INTO Answer ("UserID","RECNO","RECTYPE","RECSEQ",PutAs(NCICImage, 'JPEG'))
VALUES('hcd','0','0','1',?)
```

Here's my function to write record:

```
static void C2Search_WriteRecord(string sqlstr, Image img = null)
{
    OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand(sqlstr);
    if (img != null)
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", OdbcType.Image).Value = img;
    }
    cmd.Connection = connData;
    try
    {
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
     catch (Exception ex)
    {
        logWriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString() + ": " + ex.Message);
    }
}
```

When I execute my program using the above sql statement, I get the following message which I'm confused about:

No mapping exists from object type System.Drawing.Bitmap to a known managed provider native type.

How do I make this work as desired?

Comment: I don't think this will work, ODBC doesn't have good container read/write support in FileMaker.

Answer (score 0):

Try to rewrite the SQL statement so (I assume `NCICImage` is the target field):

```
INSERT INTO Answer ("UserID","RECNO","RECTYPE","RECSEQ", "NCICImage")
VALUES('hcd', '0', '0', '1', PutAs(?, 'JPEG'))
```

Then bind the image and make sure it's a real JPEG bytestream.